How to make a shopify app/function call an azure function
I have made a shopify app using the delivery customization framework. It has a function in the run.js
//...Above code

export async function run(input) {
  const configuration = JSON.parse(
    input?.deliveryCustomization?.metafield?.value ?? "{}"
  );
  
  
  const axios = require('axios');
  var x = 10;
  
  
  
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(functionUrl, data, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'  
            //,'x-functions-key': functionKey
        }
    });
        x = 5;
    } catch (error) {
        x = 2;
    }

//More code...

It seems like shopify does not allow async calls how can I call the azure function without using async/await.
I have tried to use a diffrent library (fetch) than axios but that did not work.
I have tried using a "then, catch" block to use a promised based system but that also did not work.

To call an Azure Function from a Shopify app function without using async/await, you can use the traditional promise-based approach with .then and .catch.
This way, you avoid using async/await and handle the asynchronous nature of the HTTP call with promises.
Here's how you can do it using axios:

const axios = require('axios');

export function run(input) {
  const configuration = JSON.parse(
    input?.deliveryCustomization?.metafield?.value ?? "{}"
  );

  const functionUrl = 'YOUR_AZURE_FUNCTION_URL';
  const data = {
    // Your data here
  };

  var x = 10;

  axios.post(functionUrl, data, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    x = 5;
    
  })
  .catch(error => {
    x = 2;

  });

  // More code...
}


The below sample code is using  axios call into the given Azure Function code.
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const axios = require('axios');

app.http('httpTrigger1', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        const name = request.query.get('name') ||  'world';

        const functionUrl = 'YOUR_URL';
        const data = {
            // Your data here
        };

        var x = 10;
        axios.post(functionUrl, data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            x = 5;
            context.log('Response from Azure Function:', response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            x = 2;
            context.log('Error calling Azure Function:', error.message);
        });

        return { body: `Hello, ${name}! The value of x is ${x}.` };
    }
});



